# How to search XTerm console history?

Tags: xterm

Is there some way to search XTerm's console history interactively, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in GNOME Terminal and Terminator?

I could run `script` in my `.bashrc` or possibly even [patch XTerm](http://ishiboo.com/~danny/Projects/xterm-patches/), but it would be nice to know if there is already some shortcut or configuration setting to do this *without* heavily modifying my runtime environment.

A way to save the entire scrollback buffer in a single operation (that is, without copying every page of it with a mouse) would be an OK fallback.

Comment: I think GNU Screen can save the terminal history. I don't know if this is the kind of thing you have in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing built in, exactly, but there are two ways to get at the scrollback text.

You can configure the `XTerm.vt100.on4Clicks` and `XTerm.vt100.on5Clicks` [resources](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#RESOURCES) (or from `on1Clicks` onwards, for that matter) to choose to copy the whole scrollback to the X11 PRIMARY selection. For example, to copy the whole scrollback on a quadruple click, put this line in your `.Xresources`:

```
XTerm.vt100.on4Clicks: all
```

You'll then have to arrange your own method for bringing up some way to search the content of the X selection, such as opening an editor or a pager with a window manager binding.

You can call the `print-everything` [action](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#KEY%20BINDINGS) to send the whole scrollback to a program determined by the `XTerm.vt100.printerCommand` resource. For example, to open the scrollback in less (running in a new xterm) when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, put these lines in your `.Xresources`:

```
XTerm.vt100.printerCommand: xterm -e sh -c 'less <&3' 3<&0
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override Ctrl ~Meta ~Shift <Key>slash: print-everything()
```

Comment: +1 [`onNClicks`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/aaa46fb6385624efef55a27a9de7679205e5a679/.Xresources#L8-L9) is great.

Comment: I already have a [`printerCommand` to save the scrollback history as HTML](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/aaa46fb6385624efef55a27a9de7679205e5a679/.Xresources#L11), so I can't override that.

Comment: @l0b0 While you can only define a single `printerCommand`, you could define it to act differently based on modifiers, e.g. bind both `Meta+M` and `Shift+Meta+M` and make your script detect whether `Shift` is pressed (which should be ok unless your computer is slow and you release `Shift` very quickly). I can't think of a shell utility for that, you can call `XKbGetState` from a small C or Python wrapper.

Comment: The less trick works great, but I do see some escape sequences on each line. With -R I see less, but still some. Can I get rid of this? Thanks.

Comment: God that -- adding less -r solves that problem.

Comment: any ideas why the less on that window will not find anything with `/` or `?`?

Answer (score 1):

Xterm does have a feature which addresses this, called *dynamic abbreviation*.  Added in [patch #188 (2004)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_188), it is optional and may not be compiled into your copy of xterm.  The [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) says:

```
   dabbrev-expand()
           Expands  the  word  before cursor by searching in the preceding
           text on the screen and  in  the  scrollback  buffer  for  words
           starting  with  that  abbreviation.  Repeating dabbrev-expand()
           several times in sequence searches for an alternative expansion
           by looking farther back.  Lack of more matches is signaled by a
           beep().  Attempts to expand an empty word (i.e., when cursor is
           preceded  by  a  space)  yield successively all previous words.
           Consecutive identical expansions are ignored.  The word here is
           defined  as a sequence of non-whitespace characters.  This fea-
           ture partially emulates the behavior of "dynamic  abbreviation"
           expansion  in  Emacs  (bound there to M-/).  Here is a resource
           setting for xterm which will do the same thing:

               *VT100*translations:    #override \n\
                       Meta <KeyPress> /:dabbrev-expand()
```

Comment: It sounds like this finds only a single word from part of that word, so it doesn't show any context.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to copy and paste all or as much of the scrollback text as you want.

Scroll back to the beginning of the text you want to copy, left-click where you want the copy to start, scroll to the end of what you want to copy, right-click, then use middle-click to paste or use xclip (-selection primary -o) to feed it to stdout or divert it into a file.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't see any way to search within XTerm's scrollback buffer to look for things. I think your only choices are to use something like `tmux` or `screen`.