# Where is terminal output stored?

Tags: terminal, gtk, terminal-emulator

I open [lxterminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/LXTerminal), which shows up in `ps` output as *x-terminal-emulator*. I then enter a command which prints it's output to STDOUT, which is visible on my screen. The command finishes, and I am shown another prompt.

The output of the previous command is still visible, so I can copy and paste it by GUI text selection, but I would like to be able to access it from a script.

Options for accessing this output that I can imagine:

1. Is it stored somewhere, like in `/dev`?
2. Is it in memory somewhere that I could read with low-level tools?
3. Can I script my terminal emulator to store the output of every command while still outputting it normally?
4. Is there a tool to scrape text from GTK windows that could access the full terminal window contents?

Comment: 1. no   2. yes;  and you can attach with `gdb` to any processs and read its memory.    3. [script(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html),  [tee(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man/tee.1.html).    4. no

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109509/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370393/117549

Comment: similar, but neither would be a duplicate

Comment: For your question #3: The `script` command can be used to produce a log file of everything displayed on a terminal. Note that the stored data includes any terminal control characters emitted by the program that produced the output, so it may not be as easy to scrape as you might think.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/483894

Answer (score 1):

Regarding number (3), you could put **"script -a <file>"** in your .bashrc / .bash_profile / etc. which will save all commands in your terminal session.