# Existing command line text on screen to file? (non-graphical Linux)

Tags: command-line, text

On tty2, how do I take a *text screenshot*  of the command line?

Comment: Related: [Where is terminal output stored?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472328)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use `tmux` or `screen`, they have the ability to save the scrollback buffer to a file.

- [Write all tmux scrollback to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/write-all-tmux-scrollback-to-a-file)
- [Copying GNU screen scrollback buffer to file (extended hardcopy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807474/copying-gnu-screen-scrollback-buffer-to-file-extended-hardcopy)

Unlike `screendump`, which is Linux-only, `tmux` and `screen` are available for BSD-based OSes too (e.g. macOS, FreeBSD) and won't require special permissions.

Comment: Because of that, I marked this one as accepted. But @RudiC Don't take it personally. Your solution is still the simplest.

Comment: Those two add another layer; you need to login and then run screen, have another shell, and then can communicate with your CLI.

Answer (score 13):

Did you consider the `screendump` command?

Comment: "Just saying `cat /dev/vcsN ` has a *similar* effect". Then why not just use `cat /dev/vcsN`?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to get it to do colour as well? (`screendump` reads from `/dev/vcsa` devices which does have colour information, but it seems to be stripped from the output.) Btw. I like to combine it with the `watch` command to see live output like `watch -n0.1 screendump`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou `/dev/vcs` devices don't contain information about the size of the screen, so `cat /dev/vcsN` only works if your terminal window has the same number of characters across as the VC you are capturing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `script` for this. It will record a typescript of the terminal session. By default, it will write to `./typescript`. Of course, you need to do this in advance so it is not really a "screenshot".

```
$ script
Script started, file is typescript
$ ls asdf
ls: cannot access asdf: No such file or directory
$ exit
Script done, file is typescript

# Then check the recordings:

$ cat typescript
Script started on Thu 29 Nov 2018 02:52:04 PM CET

$ ls asdf
ls: cannot access asf: No such file or directory
$ exit

Script done on Thu 29 Nov 2018 02:52:09 PM CET
```