# Read everything that's displayed in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tty

I am creating a terminal application that writes stuff to the terminal. And in order to test it, I really should test what's actually displayed in the terminal. Is there a way to read the data that's actually displayed in the terminal somehow?

The terminal must be some file somewhere or something, so there must be some way to read what's there.

```
cat /dev/tty
```

seems to give me a stream of data that's in there..But I don't want to see key strokes, just what I have written.

Comment: Please tell us whether or not this application is a terminal-based quasi-GUI that moves the cursor all over and maybe has pull-down menus like `mc` or `elinks`, **or** whether it it just prints streaming output to *STDOUT* and *STDERR*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the `tee` tool before all the commands you want to track. This way, you can store all your output in a selected log file.

See the example below where I save all the `bash` output to a text file called `log.txt`:

```
bash | tee log.txt
echo 'hello world'
ls
exit
cat log.txt
```

You can exit the new BASH session with a `CTRL+D` or simply type `exit` (as shown in the example above) when you're done.

If you are only looking for the commands actually passed to the terminal (it wasn't clear to me if this was what was desired by the original question), you can always just run `history` or check `~/.bash_history`

Comment: hmmm interesting yeah I get the stdin and stdout duplicated, so I get "hello world" twice in the log.txt file. How does this work exactly?

Comment: Because "cat log.txt" is still ran within the same `bash` session. In other words, it's recording the fact that you're looking at the log.txt into the log.txt, which is why it's duplicated. I adjusted the answer so that you can see where it came from.

Answer (score 3):

A few terminal programs provide screen dumps (such as [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Main-Options:XHTML-Screen-Dump)), but most do not (see [*Existing command line text on screen to file? (non-graphical Linux)*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483894/existing-command-line-text-on-screen-to-file-non-graphical-linux/484921#484921) for instance).  You could make a screenshot using a tool such as gimp, but that will not tell you what the actual characters are.  For development, I need to know that.

I'd use `script` to record the output into `typescript`.  You can `cat` it back to the screen (or use `less -R`, if the escape sequences are simple enough).  For more complicated things or long traces, I use other tools:

- [*`slowcat`*](https://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:slowcat) to slow down the `cat` progress
- [*`vile-pager`*](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/vile-snapshots/blob/master/macros/vile-pager) to filter the escapes into readable form (better than **`less`** — color sequences work across lines, but still limited to single-line cursor-movement).  That's a filter using [*vi-like-emacs*](https://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html), via a special-purpose [utility](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/vile-snapshots/blob/master/filters/manfilt.c).

To illustrate the difference, here is a screenshot of `less -r` on a `typescript` file from running `apt-get update` on one of my Debian machines:

[image]

In contrast, `vile-pager` highlights the places where the text was overwritten:

[image]

Either way (less or vile), if your application moves the cursor around the screen, the only way to review the output would be to use cat/slowcat/etc.

Answer (score -3):

```
PARAMETER_EMMC=10
while [ $PARAMETER_EMMC -eq 10 ]
    do
    read -u $USBFPI -r -n 3000 -t .3  text
        if [[ $text == *"text read from USB"* ]];  then

Execute 
fi 
done
```

Comment: Please explain what this is doing  and how somebody should use it.